# What Maven Artifact Contains javax.ws.rs.Path?

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I am working through examples in Restful Java with JAX-RS by Bill Burke.  I'm using intellij and created a Maven project to make a "Hello World" web service.  I understand that JAX-RS is a specification, and not an implementation.  I would like to try the Apache CXF implementation.

How do I find out what jar, or what Maven artifact contains the necessary classes to:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
```

Comment: Google can help you. A quick search got me among others http://aredko.blogspot.com/2013/01/going-rest-embedding-jetty-with-spring.html which provide samples (you an try newer version of the plugins)

Comment: Great.  This was the one I was looking for. Java hardcores seem to know about it, but Im not sure how you find out an artifact like that has the package your looking for.  How would I have found that on my own (ie without knowing about cxf)?  I know there is find jars, but that only listed jersey.  In general I want to get better at finding maven artifacts for certain classes.  Does anything make that easier?

Comment: Yes, the two proposed answer are what we all do. If you don't know what implementation to use, you need to google/yahoo to list the various implementation (and read what their limitation/support/dependencies/ease of use), then search on maven-oriented search sites like Central (search.maven.org)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Sounds like a slightly daunting task, faster in groups of people probably.  I grabbed cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs and am giving it a try.  That blog post is great btw, thanks for that.

Comment: Central is your friend. You can go there and search for a class name or an artifact name for nearly any open-source project, and it's defined in the Maven super POM, so anything that's on there just requires adding the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try searching for the class on [Central](http://search.maven.org). It looks like `jaxrs-api` is what you're looking for; there are a couple of different packagers, and which one you want is probably whichever goes with your container.

Answer (score 13):

Add below lines in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

g:"javax.ws.rs" AND a:"jsr311-api"

http://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 `javax.ws.rs.Path` et. al. are part of Jakarta, specifically [`jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api), currently [`jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.1.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/3.1.0/bundle)