# Cannot connect to marklogic server using java api

Tags: java, api, marklogic

I am quite new in using the java api of marklogic. I am simply trying to establish a connection to it by:

```
 DatabaseClient client =
              DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8001,
                                              "admin", "password",
                                              Authentication.DIGEST);
```

The exception I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap
at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClientImpl(DatabaseClientFactory.java:259)
at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(DatabaseClientFactory.java:253)
at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(DatabaseClientFactory.java:224)
at test_package.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 4 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a library that's needed to make this work. It seems to be part of [JSR-311](https://jsr311.java.net/). Download the jar, and make sure it's on your classpath. If you're using Maven, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139029/what-maven-artifact-contains-javax-ws-rs-path) might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

David's point is well taken. The Java API does provide a POM file for automating installation of the dependencies and, if you aren't using Maven, documents the dependencies.

In addition, you can only use the Java API after creating a MarkLogic REST server for the database.

Please see:  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro#id_69370

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum